# Making a monad succeed with failure in haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell

I have a parser monad that looks like this:

```
data Parser b a = P(b -> [(a, b)])
instance Monad (Parser p) where
  p >>= f = P $ \inp -> case parse p inp of
                           [] -> []
                           [(v, inp')] -> parse (f v) inp'
```

I also have the following functions/parsers for getting and setting the state of the parser:

```
getState :: Parser b b
getState = P(\inp -> [(inp, inp)])

setState b -> Parser b ()
setState s = P(\inp -> [(), s)]
```

Additionally, I have a Parser function that looks ahead to see if there is more to parse without consuming anything:

```
lookahead :: Parser b a -> Parser b ()
lookahead p = do
                state <- getState
                result <- p
                setState state
                return result
```

Now, suppose I want to write a Parser function that succeeds if *another parser fails*: It should fail if there are more to consume and succeed if there isn't.

```
notFollowedBy :: Parser b a -> Parser b ()
notFollowedBy p = do --statements
```

The intended usage is to disallow illegal parsers to continue, according to some grammar.

This has me kind of stumped: To my (limited) understanding of Monads, they provide you with a  safety net in case any of the evaluations fails. Is there a (good and recommended) way to make this function do the opposite?

Comment: My own Haskell experience/knowledge isn't enough to answer your question, but I must correct you on one point: monads in general have nothing to do with providing any kind of "safety net". It's true that some monads have a notion of failure "built-in" (notably `Maybe` and `Either e`), but monads in general do not.

Comment: So it actually depends on the implementation then? I thought the whole idea was to be able to string together many computations without worrying about edge cases, wouldn't that require fail safe for monads?

Comment: I'm surprised that your `Monad` instance doesn't give a syntax error. As far as I know you can't pattern match on a tuple by simply leaving out the first argument. As for the question itself, it would be tricky to answer without knowing how `Parser` is defined.

Comment: You seem to be (ab)using single-element lists as a replacement for `Maybe`. Why not just use `Maybe` directly?

Comment: Sadly I'm not free to change the definition so I have to work around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you could implement `notFollowedBy` in your parser:

```
notFollowedBy :: Parser b a -> Parser b ()
notFollowedBy p = P (\inp -> case parse p inp of
                                [] -> [((), inp)]
                                _  -> [])
```

This definition relies on being able to access the internals of `Parser` (specifically the `P` constructor).

Alternatively you can do the following:

```
notFollowedBy p = do
    inp <- getState
    case parse p inp of
        [] -> return ()
        _  -> fail "sub-parse succeeded"
```